# How to prevent NuGet assemblies from beeing copied

Tags: c#, nuget

I have a solution with multiple projects, all of these projects have dependencies aligned but one project, for some reasons, needs a specific (old) version of the dependency.

What I did was to embed the old version as a resource and using the AssemblyResolver event.

The problem is that, when I build the solution, I do not want that the old dependency being copied to the bin folder because it is resolved in-memory, I want only the latest dependency.

I am using PackageReference for all of my projects, I need a way to tell when I do not want my dependency being copied to the bin folder.

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe try adding `PrivateAssets="All"` to the `<PackageReference ...>` element? or see more options here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets - maybe it is `ExcludeAssets="All"` you want, or `IncludeAssets="compile"` ? :shrug:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Marc suggested, adding to PackageReference

```
<IncludeAssets>compile</IncludeAssets>
<PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
```

solved my problem.

Thanks!